# Updating Web Role applications (Azure) without deleting user data

Tags: deployment, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a Web Role on Azure with 2 Applications and 1 Virtual Directory.
1 Application is a backend, where admins can upload files, which are stored in the virtual directory (which is accessed by both applications).

Everytime I deploy a new version to Azure, all the uploaded content in the virtual directory is deleted - this is what I don't want!

**So how is it possible to publish a new version without deleting all my user generated files?**

I've already managed to update the application with WebDeploy. But this is only possible for the "main" application, and not the 2nd application (which is configured as a Virtual Application).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The web role is recreated on deployment. It may also occur on hardware failure, azure redeploys your system if an instance fails. Redeploys a clean virtual machine and then deploys your app to it.  You should never store data you want to keep on a web role. You need to use blob storage etc to store files you want to persist.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual directories are stored on "Application" partition which is recreated on each upgrade - see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/10/05/windows-azure-disk-partition-preservation.aspx) for more information. So the virtual directory folder is not the right place to store stuff you want preserved across upgrades. BTW the "Application" partition only has 1 gigabyte of space and some of that is used for storing your application binary code so you may find yourself in a "disk full" situation at some moment.

If you want to store some data which you don't mind sacrificing on rare occasions - like cached results - you may use "local resources" disk for that which will survive in-place upgrades and reboots. However it is not guaranteed to be preserved if your VM crashes - for such level of preservation you have to use persistent storage like blob storage for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about virtual directories and using web deploy to update application outside of the usual Azure package deployment mechanism, it sounds like your architecture/application might be more suited to a persistent VM role rather than a Web role. These are available on Azure in preview only at the moment.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/

They let you have persistent storage that will survive a recycle. The storage is actually backed by blob storage, but it looks like a normal disk from the PVM.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly VM preview is not available in Austria yet.

Comment: Azure websites may also be suitable

Comment: Azure Websites are not suitable, as you see in my requirements (2 applications with a shared virtual directory) - this won't work with websites.